# Unable to get property error in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Why is this code causing an error in IE 10?

```
function getStyles(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var elementStyles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
    return elementStyles;
}
```

The error is `Unable to get property 'getComputedStyle' of undefined or null reference` and it happens on the 3rd line.

Comment: `document.defaultView` is `undefined` or `null`. Figure out why. Based on the name of the function you're probably not supposed to access the `defaultView` there.

Comment: Are you running in compatibility view?  [According to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.defaultView)  `document.defaultView` is only supported from 9 onwards

Comment: Are you sure this error is specific to IE 10?  Have you tried running that code in Chrome, Firefox, or other browsers?

Comment: have you tried `window.getComputedStyle(element, null);`

Comment: @Halcyon it's working fine in chrome.

Comment: @DominatorX yes this error happens only in ie.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are in quirks mode. In quirks mode, IE 10 acts like 8 (doesn't support `document.defaultView`). So, use `parentWindow` instead of `defaultView`.

Comment: Or, bring yourself out of quirks mode :) That is usually the better solution to problems like these, unless you're working on legacy intranet applications that would need serious attention to work in IE 10. IE 11 has Enterprise Mode, which can run these types of sites really effectively.